# Can't find the form I created on Cognito Forms when I log in to my account

Tags: cognito-forms

I am switching from Adobe Forms.  I just created a Cognito account and created a new form from scratch.  I closed out so I could test the system.  When I log back in, I see my account, but I don't see a tab with my form.  How do I access my form to view entries, edit etc...

Answer (score 1):

Please go to https://www.cognitoforms.com/support as submit a bug report so we can assist you directly.

Also, if you built the form using our [Try It Now](http://forms.jamie.cognito.test/forms/build) option on the home page, you can take the following steps to access this form and save it to your organization:

1. Log out of Cognito Forms
2. Click Try It Now on the home page
3. Your form should appear in the builder
4. Click Save and then login to your account to save your form